# How can I do a global regular expression match in Perl?

Tags: php, regex, perl, preg-match-all

I am trying to come up with a regular expression in Perl matching multiple patterns and returning all of them like `preg_match_all` in PHP does.

Here's what I have:

```
$str = 'testdatastring';
if($str =~ /(test|data|string)/) {
        print "its found index location: $0 $-[0]-$+[0]\n";
        print "its found index location: $1 $-[1]-$+[1]\n";
        print "its found index location: $2 $-[2]-$+[2]\n";
        print "its found index location: $3 $-[3]-$+[3]\n";
}
```

This only gives me the first match which in this is 'test'.  I want to be able to match all occurrences of specified patterns: 'test', 'data' and 'string'.

I know that in PHP, you can use preg_match_all for this kind of purpose:

```
if(preg_match_all('/(test|data|string)/', 'testdatastring', $m)) {
        echo var_export($m, true);
}
```

The above PHP code would match all 3 strings: 'test', 'data' and 'string'.

I want to know how to do this in Perl.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Perl equivalent to

```
preg_match_all('/(test|data|string)/', 'testdatastring', $m)
```

is

```
@m = ("testdatastring" =~ m/(test|data|string)/g);
```

The /g flag stands for global, so it returns a list of matches in list context.

Comment: How do you apply this in an if/else statement ?

Comment: Worked it out : if (@list = $str =~ Regex){True}{False} use /regex/g to group the found items into the list.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.anaesthetist.com/mnm/perl/regex.htm .  Basic syntax (from there) is:

```
$_ = "alpha xbetay xgammay xdeltay so on";
($first, $second, $third) = /x(.+?)y/g;
```

Note the /g