# Perl regex disable parenthesis extraction

Tags: regex, perl, extract

I am trying something that I found on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948795/how-can-i-do-a-global-regular-expression-match-in-perl) but I am having some problems:

I know that there are better regex for URLs but consider this for example:

```
@links=($content =~ m/(https?)?.*[.]com/g);
*$content has text or html
```

The part `(https?)?` is for links like `www.google.com`, but having the parenthesis it returns `"http"` to `$1` which is put into `@links`! That is a problem, since I want the whole link.

What would globally extract *simple* links (or whatever regex is specified) from text and put them into a list?
By simple, I mean:

- `http://www.google.com`
- `www.google.com`
- `google.com`
- `https://www.google.com`

Comment: adding `?:` right after the opening parenthesis will make it non-capturing. does that help?

Comment: Perhaps the following related topic will help: [How can I extract URL and link text from HTML in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254345/how-can-i-extract-url-and-link-text-from-html-in-perl)

Comment: perfectly! thanks! :) Im still open to hearing better alternatives @m.buettner

Comment: @m.buettner Make your comment an answer - I think it's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-capturing version looks like this:

```
m/(?:https?)?.*[.]com/g
```

For capturing links, I use this regex, derived from URI::Find:

```
m<https?://[;/\?:\@&=+\$,\[\]A-Za-z0-9\-_.!~*'()%#]*[/\?:\@&=+\$\[A-Za-z0-9\-_!~*(%#]>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is too naive, it won't catch many other URLs.
Instead, use Regexp::Common, like this:

```
use Regexp::Common qw/URI/;

my @links = ($content =~ /$RE{URI}/g);
```

This works for HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc and properly captures more advanced combinations for URL parameters.

Comment: Thank you! i have used these kind of modules before (when I tried to build some kind of crawler bot) but I just wanted to know about disabling the parenthesis for whatever purpose! Not for URLs in particular. Thanks though

Comment: @fersarr if an answer has resolved the issue you were asking about you should accept the answer by clicking the *tick* icon below the up/down vote buttons. This will mark the issue as resolved and award points to the person answering the question thus motivating other people to answer your future questions.