# How to find all instances of text between two delimiters (perl)?

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to parse the text

```
==== Example 1 ====
Some text that doesn't contain 4 equals signs
==== Example 2 ====
More text that doesn't contain 4 equals signs
==== Example 3 ====
Even more text that doesn't contain 4 equals signs
```

My goal is to get an array with elements "Example 1", "Example 2", and "Example 3" using RegEx in Perl. I'm a beginner in Perl and RegEx, so initially I used the greedy method which returned text I din't want. When I later used a non-greedy method, I was only able to get "Example 1." My latest attempt:

```
my @matches = ($text =~ /====(*?[ -~\s])====/g);
```

**Edit**: I realize how to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237/regex-to-pull-out-a-sub-string-between-two-tags-in-a-string); instead I want to return multiple matches instead of one.

Comment: Did you try the global modifier at the end of your RegEx? [`/regex/g`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948795/how-can-i-do-a-global-regular-expression-match-in-perl).

Comment: "*... initially I used ... When I later used ...*" Can you include a snippet of code from your attempts? Showing precisely [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) can help in providing a useful answer.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I've just added what I've tried.

Comment: Why not `/====\s?(.*?)\s?====/g`? Not perfect, but if your cases are pretty simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not `/====\s?(.*?)\s?====/g`?

Not perfect, but if your cases are pretty simple...