# Parenthesis text capturing (Perl RegEx)

Tags: regex, perl

I'm back with a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393541/how-to-find-all-instances-of-text-between-two-delimiters-perl).
Let's assume I have the text

```
====Example 1====
Some text that I want to get that
may include line breaks
or special ~!@#$%^&*() characters

====Example 2====
Some more text that I don't want to get.
```

and use  `$output = ($text =~ ====Example 1====\s*(.*?)\s*====);` to try and get everything from "====Example 1====" to the four equal signs right before "Example 2".

Based on what I've seen [on this site](http://fiddle.re/zg9uv), [regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com), and by running it myself, Perl finds and matches the text, but $output remains null or is assigned "1". I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong with the capturing parenthesis, but I can't figure out what. Any help would be appreciated.
My full code is:

```
$text = "====Example 1====\n
Some text that I want to get this text\n
may include line breaks\n
or special ~!@#$%^&*() characters\n
\n
====Example 2====]\n
Some more filler text that I don't want to get.";
my ($output) = $text =~ /====Example 1====\s*(.*?)\s*====/;
die "un-defined" unless defined $output;
print $output;
```

Comment: my ($output) = $text =~ /====Example 1====\s*(.*?)\s*====/;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. Apply the /s flag to the regex to let it know that the input to the regex might be multiple lines.
2. Switch your parenthesis to be around `$output` instead of around the `($text ~= regex);`.

Example:

`($output) = $text =~ /====Example\s1====\s*(.*?)\s*====/s;`

For example, putting it into a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$text="
====Example 1====
Some text that I want to get that
may include line breaks
or special ~!@#$%^&*() characters

====Example 2====
Some more text that I don't want to get.
";

print "full text:","\n";
&hr;
print "$text","\n";
&hr;

($output) = $text =~ /====Example\s1====\s*(.*?)\s*====/s;
print "desired output of regex:","\n";
&hr;
print "$output","\n";
&hr;

sub hr {
        print "-" x 80, "\n";
}
```

Leaves you output like:

```
bash$ perl test.pl
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
full text:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

====Example 1====
Some text that I want to get that
may include line breaks
or special ~!@#0^&*() characters

====Example 2====
Some more text that I don't want to get.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
desired output of regex:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Some text that I want to get that
may include line breaks
or special ~!@#0^&*() characters
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with parentheses to force list context, and use `/s` when matching so `.` can also match newlines,

```
my ($output) = $text =~ / /s;
```

Comment: Tried, but `$output` still remains null.